# What value of ICC to use when calculating effective sample size?

Tags: sample-size, intraclass-correlation, cluster-sample

What value of ICC should I use when calculating the effective sample size of clustered data?

A previous publication conducting a similar study reported ICCs of 0.04 for the full mixed model (random intercept plus individual and household-level variables) and 0.19 for the null model (only the intercept term).

Which value should I use to calculate the effective sample size in my study? In terms of structure, their full model most closely resembles the data structure of the model I am working with, so my gut feeling is 0.04, but I am uncertain.